# Git flow - comandos em lote

Tags: git, git-flow

Cada vez que finalizou um branch, seja release, feature ou hotfix tenho que seguir uma série de comandos para publicar as alterações no meu repositório.
Por exemplo:
Vou finalizar uma hotfix de nome ht001 então eu faço:

```
git flow hotfix finish ht001
git checkout develop
git push
git checkout master
git push
git push origin ht001
```

Obviamente poderia executar tudo em um só comando usando &&

Isso tudo porque finish faz tudo localmente
Ao finalizar este comando executa localmente
publica minhas alterações locais
merger em master
merger em develop
tag ht001

Eu gostaria de ao dar o finish, ele já publicasse também em meu repositório as alterações.

Tem com ou sempre será necessário executar todos os comandos em conjunto com git flow.

OBS. Não estou usando inteface gráfica para controle e não gostaria de usar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode criar um *alias* de git contendo uma função `bash` que faça o que você precisa, inserindo-a na seção `[alias]` do seu arquivo `.gitconfig`:

```
[alias]
        pub = "!f() { git flow hotfix finish \"$1\" && git checkout develop git push && git checkout master && git push && git push origin \"$1\"; }; f"
```

Assim, ao executar o alias `git pub` acima, você só precisa passar o nome da sua hotfix:

```
$ git pub ht001
```

Os comandos foram encadeados com uso de `&&` para garantir que cada um deles só será executado se o comando anterior finalizar com sucesso.

Como o comando em si é executado pela shell, trata-se de um `shell script`. "Desenrolado" em várias linhas, seria assim:

```
f() { 
    git flow hotfix finish \"$1\" &&
    git checkout develop git push &&
    git checkout master &&
    git push &&
    git push origin \"$1\"; 
}; 
f
```

Ou seja, criamos uma função chamada `f`, dentro dela executamos aquilo que precisamos fazer, utilizando os parâmetros posicionais passados para o alias através das variáveis numéricas $1, $2 etc, e por fim fazemos a chamada da função `f` recém-declarada.

Assim, toda vez que você executa `git pub x`, o git declara a função `f()` e logo depois a executa, passando como parâmetro o `x`.

Lembre-se que aliases iniciados em "!" são executados pela shell sempre a partir no diretório raiz do seu repositório, portanto evite utilizar caminhos relativos dentro do script.

Comment: +1, eu uso alias mas não sabia que era possível passar uma "variável"(no caso o nome da hotfix). só fiquei na dúvida o significado do `f()`

Comment: É uma declaração de função da shell, pra ser chamada logo adiante. Assim você pode manipular os parâmetros posicionais passados pro git usando as variáveis de atributo numéricas.